How do I restore contents of my Notes.app?
This is happening on a 2020 iMac running macOS Sequoia 15.2.
One of the multiple notes in the Notes.app was blank when I opened it. Here is what I tried to restore it.
After quitting Notes.app and turning off syncing in iCloud, I went to ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/, browsed TimeMachine and restored the three files at the end of that path: NotesV7.storedata, NotesV7.store-shm, NotesV7.store-wal.
When after doing so I launched the Notes.app, there were zero notes.
My plan was to copy the text from the missing note, go back into Time Machine and restore those same three files from yesterday's backup, the create a new note and paste the text I saved into that note.
Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Do you synchronize the notes with iCloud or any other cloud service?

I don't use Notes, so I've never had any reason to try, but TM doesn't actually interface to the Notes app?  You have to manipulate files under it and hope it notices?

Yes, my notes are synced with iCloud.

No TM does not interface with the Notes.app.  You have to find the files in which the notes are saved and restore those files, then open Notes.app again and, if you have chosen the correct file, Notes should be populated by what is stored in that file.

That doesn't sound right, but maybe Sequoia changes things.  In Ventura, there's a SQLite db in that directory.  Your .storedata file might be the SQLite db, dunno.

If possible, follow the instructions on the following support page under "Recover recently deleted notes": https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/icloud/mm2f42f05cb9/icloud#:~:text=You%20can%20recover%20and%20edit,folder%20list%20on%20the%20left.

Thank you for the link to the Apple support article.  I knew about the "30-day recovery rule", but my note was accidentally deleted some months ago.  It is interesting to note, BTW, that when you go to iCloud.com, and scroll down to [Data Recovery] you can restore items from Files, Bookmarks, Contacts, and Calendars, but. not Notes.  Wonder why that is?  As to the SQLite files:  in Sequoia/User Library/Containers/ there are three folders named Notes.  More, later, after I have looked into the sub folders in each of them.

Using Find Any File here is a path I found: /Users/bobg/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes at the end of which I did indeed find three SQlite files:  NoteStore.sqlite-wal; NoteStore.sqlite-shm; NoteStore.sqlite. I wonder if one or more of them - if I go back far enough in TM - is/are the files I would need to restore to recover a long-ago deleted note?

Make sure you have a Time Machine backup of the current state of all data.
First, in the Notes settings, check the box to "Enable the On My Mac account." Move all your iCloud notes into the On My Mac account. Then quit Notes.
Disconnect from the Internet by turning off Wi-Fi and/or unplugging the network cable, as applicable.
Next, restore from Time Machine the whole folder ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes and also the folders in ~/Library/Containers related to Notes.
Relaunch Notes. You should now see your notes as they were at the time of the snapshot you restored from. Move any of those notes that you want to keep to the On My Mac account. Leave the rest alone.
Reconnect to the Internet. The latest versions of your iCloud notes should be restored, overwriting the older versions. You can then move the notes you moved into On My Mac back to iCloud.

Aha!  So those are the correct folders (and all their contents) to restore.  Thank you so much, Mr. D!  No wonder I made a mess of it on my first effort!
